# Droid Razr - is it a high, medium, or low dpi device?

Tags: android

I am developing for my own phone, no intention of marketing my app.  Does anyone know if the Razr is a h, m, or l device?  I am a ways from deploying to my actual phone.

Comment: we need you to be more specific on which model it is.

Comment: @AaronRussell There's more than one model of the Droid RAZR?

Comment: @millimoose Yes, RAZR MAXX, RAZR V MT887...

Comment: @miqbal All of which have the same size and resolution display.

Comment: @millimoose you're right. But you should asked that "There's more than one model which has different screen size?"

Answer (score 2):

Droid Razr has a resolution of 960 by 540 right? if so, it should be a hdpi device.